# Selectable/Highlightable List Item with custom background

Tags: android, android-listview, android-xml, listviewitem

I have a `ListView` item which has a set background. This overrides the default blue highlight that appears when the item is pressed/selected.  Is there a way to have both the background and the selector?

This is my attempt at merging both a background and selector...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/red"/>

    </selector>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:dither="true"
            android:shape="rectangle" >

            <solid android:color="#ccc" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape
            android:dither="true"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />

            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

             </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

This is in my `drawable` folder, and I set it with this in my ListItem xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_background
```

Comment: Try to set your custom color in parent's View background=orange. Than add selectableItemBackground to chilldren View background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as this is getting a bit of attention again,  I will post the solution I found (which I had previously mentioned in a comment):

I found `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` in the ListView solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To have a custom background and the default selector effect (another drawalbe when pressed / selected) is a little difficult, after a few tries, I made it.

You should define two selectors in separated xml file: `listitem_background.xml` and `listitem_selector.xml`.

The first one is used to the background of the list item, it will make the effect when the item is pressed and in normal state.

The second one is used to the selector of the list, it will get rid of the default selector of the list view by setting all the state to `transparent`.

The default selector effect is defined in the first xml file: listitem_background.xml.

#### First you need a xml file to define some drawable color: `color_drawable.xml`, in `res/values` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- The color of the normal state. -->
    <drawable name="listitem_normal">#E671B8</drawable>
    <!-- The two color below show when the item is pressed, you should change that to the color you want. -->
    <drawable name="listitem_pressed">#e7eeab</drawable>
    <drawable name="listitem_selected">#e7eeab</drawable>

</resources>
```

#### Then, `listitem_background.xml` in `res/drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_selected" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_selected" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_normal"/>

</selector>
```

#### and, `listitem_selector.xml` in `res/drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/android:transparent"/>

</selector>
```

#### set listitem_background to listitem:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_background" >

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### set listitem_selector to listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listitem_selector" />
```

Comment: This still doesn't allow me to use my custom rectangular background on the list item.  For the background of the list item. I tried adding the selector to my background but that did not make a difference.  I found `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` in the ListView actually solved the problem on its own though.

Comment: Sorry that it did not work for you, I had tested in the app I sent back to your. Anyway, congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Just use of this in ListView to match the color combination

android:cacheColorHint="#e7eeab"

Comment: This hasn't made a difference, unfortunately